# Why does Audacity doesn't work properly in Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: audacity

I have audacity running well on a laptop with ubuntu 15.04 but on another computer with Ubuntu 14.10, it simply doesn't work, vlc and clementine work well with sound but when I try to record or play sound with audacity in Ubuntu 14.10, audacity plays noise, and after playing it one or two times it crashes.

After this, I tried to install audacity from source, but libsndfile was replaced in repositories by libsndfile1 so it gives me an error.